# Query.startAt() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a custom object

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I am trying to implement a search functionality. When a user type something in the input box after hitting enter it will search in firebase collection and filter out only the select results and populate a list. In my collection there are many fields and I want to create the search function for all the fields. After writing something in the textbox and when I press Enter getting an error **Query.startAt() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a custom object**. Maybe I will have to typecast the value type which I am getting from the inputbox.

[image]

Component.html -

```
<div class="search-pets">
 <input type="text" class="search-pet-input" placeholder="SEARCH..."(keydown.enter)="searchPets($event) ">
</div>

<div class="single-pet-list" *ngFor="let pet of allPets">
  <div class="pet-listing-header-owner">
   <p>{{ pet.OwnerName }}</p>
  </div>
  <div class="pet-listing-header-petname">
   <p>{{ pet.PetName }}</p>
  </div>
  <div class="pet-listing-header-petname">
    <p>{{ pet.PetType }}</p>
  </div>
  <div class="pet-listing-header-petbreed">
     <p>{{ pet.PetBreed }}</p>
  </div>
  <div class="pet-listing-header-petname">
     <p>{{ pet.PetSize }}</p>
  </div>
  <div class="pet-listing-header-date">
     <p>{{ pet.createdDate }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Component.ts -

```
public allPets: any;
public startAt = new Subject();
public endAt = new Subject();

searchPets($event){
    console.log($event.target.value);

    let q = $event.target.value
    this.startAt.next(q)
    this.endAt.next(q+"\uf8ff")

    this.petservice.searchPets(this.startAt, this.endAt).subscribe(res => {
      this.allPets = res;
    })
  }
```

PetService.ts -

```
searchPets(start, end) {
    return this.afs
      .collection<any>("pets", ref =>
        ref
          .limit(4)
          .orderBy("OwnerName")
          .orderBy("PetName")
          .orderBy("PetBreed")
          .orderBy("PetType")
          .orderBy("PetSize")
          .startAt(start)
          .endAt(end)
      )
      .valueChanges();
  }
```

Comment: What is `start` equal to?

Comment: You're passing a Subject to .startAt(). That's not what startAt expects. It expects a DocumentSnapshot, or an array of field values. Use TypeScript to specify types for your arguments, so that the compiler tells you when you're doing something wrong. Also specify the generic type for your Subjects. You're shooting yourself in the foot by not using types.

Comment: @Peter Haddad start is value that a user is entering in the input field which is subject() that I have declared on the top.

Comment: @JB Nizet  basically I was checking this https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/autocomplete-search-with-angular4-and-firebase/ and trying to implement. I think he have done the same thing.

Comment: As the comments below the article show, this article is outdated, and was written for an old version of angularfire

Comment: Can you please suggest what I can do solve this or how how can specify the type and pass the value.

Answer (score 0):

`startAt` and `endAt` accept only strings whereas in your code, you are passing through `Subject` objects.

To fix the syntax error in your query, you would need to change your `Component.ts` to the following:

```
public allPets: any;

searchPets($event){
    let q = $event.target.value + "";

    console.log("Searching pets: ", q);

    this.petservice.searchPets(q, q+"\uf8ff").subscribe(res => {
      this.allPets = res;
    });
  }
```